# Arbitrary-Response Filter Design

Tags: matlab, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, parks-mclellan

I want to design a FIR filter by using  'cfirpm' function , which can i use the group delay and grid frequency,
my code is :

```
N=30 ;
f=[linspace(-1,-.5,120),linspace(-0.4,0.7,60),linspace(0.8,1,90)];
d=[zeros(1,120),ones(1,60),zeros(1,90)].*exp(-j*pi*f*N-1/2);
b=cfirpm(N,d,@lowpass);
fvtool(b,1,'OverlayedAnalysis','phase');
```

But i got the following error in matlab,

```
Error using cfirpm
Band edges must be monotonically increasing.
```

How can i solve this problem? or,how can i add the group delay in this function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a low-pass filter it is sufficient to specify the band edges, as shown in [this example](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cfirpm.html#f6-905353) on the mathworks website. From your code I suppose that your band edges are

`f=[-1,-0.5,-0.4,0.7,0.8,1]`

Note that you wrote `-0.7` and `-0.8` (i.e., with a negative sign), which I assume is a mistake.

Furthermore, think about the desired phase or group delay response. The phase factor `exp(-j*pi*f*N-1/2)` does not make much sense, an it is probably not what you mean. If you want a linear phase (with delay $N/2$, where $N$ is the filter *order*) there is no need to use `cfirpm`, and you could better use [firpm](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html?searchHighlight=firpm&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

Comment: Using Wolfram over the free web interface I get the "Standard computation time exceeded..." error with the following "int (r^2-x^2)^(3/2), x=-r to r" ... ? quite strange?

Comment: @Fat32: Somehow I get the feeling that this comment doesn't belong here ...

Comment: As far as I remember, from time to time, you suggest using Wolfram alfa for symbollic expression evaluations (especially for integrals and sums) . So I felt that I should immediately ask it to you, after getting this weird time-out response? So I wondered if u also get that error. btw I know this is not the place :-)

Comment: @Fat32: OK, I thought it would refer to some other answer ... and, no, I have no idea what's going on; sometimes it does time-out on me too, sometimes it even gives me a wrong result (unless I'm mistaken ...)

Comment: @Fat32: And if I'm not missing anything, it doesn't look like the most straightforward integral anyway.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Sorry for the puzzling intro. The answer from an integral table is $$\int (r^2-x^2)^{3/2}dx = \frac{x(r^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{4} + \frac{3 r^2 x (r^2-x^2)^{1/2}}{8} + \frac{3 r^4}{8} \sin^{-1}(x/r) $$ Not simple but not very complex too (though I can't figure out now which technique to use), and probably quite a popular integrand to disclude from the non-pro version... btw, I can delete my comments if that's necessary.